# Water-damaged Indian passport expiring in November 2020

Tags: passports, damaged-passports

My passport is expiring in Nov 2020 and it has water damage.  I live close to Houston.  It is hard to get an answer from the consulate, so asking here.  When I fill the online form at CKGS (https://passport.in.ckgs.us/get-started), do I pick "damaged passport" or "expiring passport"?

Comment: You are applying to renew your passport 9 months before it expires, assuming you are doing that because it is damaged, the correct answer is *damaged passport*.

Answer (score 3):

If the passport is actually damaged, you should select damaged instead of due to expire.

The help text from that web site explains:

> Different kinds of damage that will qualify a passport as "Damaged" are as below:
>
> - Water damage that has made the stamps and/or Consulate signature blurred.
> - Any rips or tears to the passport pages.
> - If there is scribbling from a pen on the pages (i.e. children writing in passport).
> - Ink blots that cover the photo or any detail information.
> - Any damage that causes the photo or passport details to be unreadable.
> - CKGS or EOI/Consulate may notify at later stage – if passport falls under damaged category in cases where applicant does not select the correct option at the first place.

It is clear that they expect you to select damaged if the passport is damaged and that there may be a problem if you do not select damaged.