# Do I need to replace my passport if a stamp on the front page is slightly water damaged?

Tags: indian-citizens, applications, passport-stamps, us-visa

Should I go for a re-issue of my passport? The front page of my passport is showing water damage. My name, passport number, and photos are intact.

I want to apply for a US visa in February. Should I go for renewal or ask the regional passport service regarding this issue?[image: Indian passport page with some ink bleeding on one stamp]

Comment: Unfortunately no Indian govt website grades degree of damage. They just say that if name, passport number or photo is not visible then passport is "damaged beyond recognition" otherwise it is just "damaged". [This answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/153353) has text from an Indian consulate website which states that blurred stamps or signatures are "damage". To be safe you should reissue the passport. The process is less strict for "damaged" passports than for "damaged beyond recognition" passports.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely go for further information regarding this reissue and all in passport office.

Comment: I have same issue can you tell have you replace your passport or not Have you become successful to got visa on your damaged passport